# MDT 2012 - Use custom pane variable in customsetting.ini

Tags: mdt-2012, mdt

I have a deployment share that allows me to deploy a single image across several sites. Each site has its own default applications and other specific parameters ( WSUS , etc).

For a more automated deployment possible, I created a custom panel that lets you select the site in question so that applications and other parameters are pre- selected.

Since customsettings.ini file is evaluated before displaying the wizard I can not use the variable created in my custom panel.

Based on this [website](http://adminnexus.blogspot.ca/2012/09/checking-applications-in-mdt-wizard.html) I raised the ZTIGather.wsf script to validate my custom panel. The script runs but the variable used in the custom panel still not applied to customsettings.ini.

Have you do something similar? Is it only possible to do this ? I 'm open to suggestions.